# SQL Query using Random

Tags: mysql

Hi could anyone help me with something?

I need a mysql query that can return 4 values from a column in some table, also select all fiels from each row.

something like:

```
SELECT * FROM dadoslivros WHERE RAND() =1 limit 100;
```

But i only want the random form row ID.

Thanks.

Comment: How about ordering your results randomly? `SELECT * FROM dadoslivros ORDER BY RAND()` LIMIT 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you just want to use `ORDER BY RAND()`:

```
select *
from dadoslivros
order by rand()
limit 100
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/480be/1)